# How to Know a given Font is an OpenType font or Not

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way in C# to find out a given font is an opentype font or not.
like when we open a FontDialog in Winform and choose an openType font from the list, and press on Ok button it will popup a Dialogbox with **Only TrueType fonts are supported. This is not a TrueType font.** ,Exception Message.

So i want to know what kind of logic has been implemented in FontDialog for checking the Font , that this is a OpenType font or this is a truetype font.

I have a list of System.Windows.Media.FontFamily and i want to tell a user you have selected a OpenType font and you have selected non open type font.

Code is

```
var vFonts = System.Windows.Media.Fonts.SystemFontFamilies;
foreach (System.Windows.Media.FontFamily fontFamily in vFonts)
{
     m_lstFont.Add(fontFamily.Source);
}
```

and when a user select any font from m_lstFont it will popup a Dialog you have selected a OpenType font or you have selected non open type font.

Answer (score 0):

The open types have a suffix (file extension) of `otf`.

Comment: How do you get the suffix?

Comment: Thanks for valuable answer but when a end user change the suffixe of the fontfile, like from .otf it chnage to .ttf, in that case it will says that this this is non opentype but actually this font is a opentype.